# Combine two rows in R that are separated

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to clean the dataset so that all data is in its appropriate cell by combining rows since they are oddly separated. There is an obvious nuance to the dataset in that there are some rows that are correctly coded and there are some that are not.

Here is an example of the data:

| Rank | Store | City | Address | Transactions | Avg. Value | Dollar Sales Amt. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 1404 | State College | Hamilton Square Shop Center |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | 230 W Hamilton Ave | 155548 | 52.86 | 8263499 |
| 41 | 2310 | Springfield | 149 Baltimore Pike | 300258 | 27.24 | 8211137 |
| 42 | 2514 | Erie | Yorktown Centre |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | 2501 West 12th Street | 190305 | 41.17 | 7862624 |

Here is an example of how I want the data:

| Rank | Store | City | Address | Transactions | Avg. Value | Dollar Sales Amt. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 1404 | State College | Hamilton Square Shop Center, 230 W Hamilton Ave | 155548 | 52.86 | 8263499 |
| 41 | 2310 | Springfield | 149 Baltimore Pike | 300258 | 27.28 | 8211137 |
| 42 | 2514 | Erie | Yorktown Centre, 2501 West 12th Street | 190305 | 41.17 | 7862624 |

Is there an Excel or R function to fix this, or does anyone know how to write an R functional to correct this?

I read into the CONCATENATE function in excel and realized it was not going to accomplish anything. I figured an R functional would be the only way to fix this.

Comment: Can you show the `dput(yourexampledata)`

Comment: And what's the source if this dataset? Perhaps an issue with input file is parsing?

Comment: Since this is not a free code-writing service, please show your attempts at solving it, even if not successful. One way to solve this easily is with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenate function will work here or in the excel select the columns and by using the merge formula in the formala option you can complete the task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking how the file is being parsed.
From the example data you provided, it looks like the address column is being
split on ", " and going to the next line.
Based on this assumption alone, below is a potential solution using the
tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
original_data <- tibble(Rank = c(40,NA,41,42,NA),
                        Store = c(1404,NA,2310,2514,NA),
                        City = c("State College",NA,"Springfield","Erie",NA),
                        Address = c("Hamilton Square Shop Center",
                                    "230 W Hamilton Ave","149 Baltimore Pike",
                                    "Yorktown Centre","2501 West 12th Street"),
                        Transactions = c(NA,155548,300258,NA,190305),
                        `Avg. Value` = c(NA,52.86,27.24,NA,41.17),
                        `Dollar Sales Amt.` = c(NA,8263499,8211137,NA,7862624))

new_data <- original_data %>%
    fill(Rank:City) %>%
    group_by_at(vars(Rank:City)) %>%
    mutate(Address1 = lag(Address)) %>%
    slice(n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Address = if_else(is.na(Address1), Address,
                             str_c(Address1, Address, sep = ", "))) %>%
    select(Rank:`Dollar Sales Amt.`)

new_data
```